# How does the new Sangan errata affect Exodia?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

Just reading up on the new sangan errata which is;

> If this card is sent from the field to the Graveyard: Add 1 monster with 1500 or less ATK from your Deck to your hand, but you cannot activate cards, or the effects of cards, with that name for the rest of this turn. You can only use this effect of "Sangan" once per turn.

So this new Errata states that you cant use the effect of the monster you added until the turn after you use this effect.

To my understanding this means that if you have sangan in an exodia deck and you have both legs and both arms in your hand then if you use the sangan effect to add the head then you wont win until your next turn. Or would the effect of exodia overrule this effect?

And also if you have the head already and three of the other pieces in your hand when you use sangan to add the last one it doesnt have an effect because only the head has the effect and because you havent added the head to your hand then the win condition can still be activated. Or would you still have to wait a turn because the pieces are listed in the effect of the head?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Having all five pieces of Exodia triggers a win condition, not a monster effect. No card may directly prevent this win condition from triggering.

No card may negate or override the win condition printed on Exodia the Forbidden One. There are multiple rulings to this effect in OCG, including that Prohibition cannot block the effect of Exodia the Forbidden One (this ruling in particular is among those that UDE also issued independently for TCG, before Konami took that over).

There are only three situations in which a player with all five pieces of Exodia will not win:

- The player drew the remaining piece(s) of Exodia as a result of an effect that requires them to draw X cards and then discard X cards from their hand (e.g. Graceful Charity - Draw 3, then Discard 2). Exodia's win condition will not be checked until after the cards are discarded from the player's hand.
- Both players were required to draw cards (e.g. Morphing Jar), and as a result of that, both players now have all five pieces of Exodia in their hand. The official ruling in OCG (and unofficial from UDE) is a draw.
- The player had only the remaining piece of Exodia in their deck and was required to draw two cards from a single card effect (e.g. Pot of Greed). The first draw will add Exodia to their hand, completing Exodia. The second draw causes them to lose the game via Deck-out, before Exodia's win condition is checked for.

Exodia's win condition also occurs before any cards can react to the event that caused its satisfaction (e.g. Magical Thorn) and prevents the remainder of any chain in progress from resolving (e.g. if "Backup Soldier" is played against "Delinquent Duo" and "Backup Soldier" results in Exodia being completed, Delinquent Duo no longer resolves as the game has already ended)

Comment: as far as i was aware the win condition was due to the *effect* of exodia implying that it could be negated due to sangan's new effect

Comment: Exodia has no effect, but a condition

Comment: @WhatsThePoint Exoida effect: {**If** you have "Right Leg of the Forbidden One", "Left Leg of the Forbidden One", "Right Arm of the Forbidden One" and "Left Arm of the Forbidden One" in addition to this card in your hand, **you win** the Duel.} this statement means it's not an effect, it's a condition as user20357 mentioned