# Yu-gi-oh the big Question about Exodia

Tags: yu-gi-oh

Are you able to beat Exodia?

I think you must destroy one of the pieces to him or you can't. Is this true?

Comment: Related: https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/35388/how-does-the-new-sangan-errata-affect-exodia  Not a duplicate, but the first answer to that question should answer your question as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can only prevent him from being activated in the hand by removing it from the players hand with cards like "dragged down into the grave". Then maybe soul release to banish it but there are several cards that help Exodia back into their deck or/and hand. Like different dimension burial to recover from banishment, then backup soldier. If I were you I'd always go for the head first because he is catalyst all the other pieces mean nothing without it.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be coming with the assumption that [Exodia](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Exodia_the_Forbidden_One) is played piece by piece, it is not. The card says (emphasis mine):

> If you have "Right Leg of the Forbidden One", "Left Leg of the Forbidden One", "Right Arm of the Forbidden One" and "Left Arm of the Forbidden One" in addition to this card **in your hand**, you win the Duel.

You won't be able to destroy the parts, but there are ways to handle it in he deck or hand before they get all the pieces. Every piece of Exodia is limited, only one copy per deck, so getting rid of enough parts will ruin it as a win condition, this is also a part of why Exodia is not a common strategy to play.

Sending cards to grave or banishing them can help you with this, however interaction with both means that is not a guarantee they will stay in grave or banished. Some examples:

- [Burial from a Different Dimension](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Burial_from_a_Different_Dimension) - can put up to three monsters, up to three parts of Exodia, back into the grave from banish.
- [Dark Erruption](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Dark_Eruption) - Return a dark monster from the grave to the hand, all parts of exodia are dark.
- [Dark Factory of Mass Production](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Dark_Factory_of_Mass_Production) - Return up to two normal monsters from the grave to the hand, all but the core part of Exodia is normal.